# How to do index parsing in expect script

Tags: perl, scripting, expect

I have a code from perl which I need to convert to .expect script to check if -T is present and then use the next one as a timeout..  basically check the arg count, see if -T is one of them.

Perl code:

```
# check command line against valid arguments
%opt=();
unless( getopts('T:', \%opt) )
    {
      print("$progname : Illegal command line arguments\n");
      exit(1);
    } 
$commandTimeout=$opt{T} if $opt{T};
$inputCommand = join(" ", @ARGV); # convert arguments into one (long) string
```

Comment: You might want to use the [cmdline package](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.html) from tcllib

Answer (score 0):

Expect uses Tcl which is also a general purpose programming language. You can go through the command line arguments by your self.

```
[user@host] # cat foo.tcl
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $argv]} {incr i} {
    puts "argv\[$i]=[lindex $argv $i]"
}

foreach arg $argv {
    puts "$arg"
}
[user@host] # tclsh foo.tcl hello world
argv[0]=hello
argv[1]=world
hello
world
[user@host] #
```

For more info, see [Tcl's doc](http://tcl.tk/doc/).